# Killing Application Window with Bash/Terminal

Tags: macos, bash, unix, terminal

I'm trying to close an open window in Preview by using the terminal. Everything that I have found on the internet suggests using AppleScript instead, but I cannot do such since the plist option does not exist for me (to enable osascript for preview as indicated here on [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/526624/how-do-i-close-a-window-from-an-application-passing-the-file-name)). I am running OS X 10.8.2.

I should note here that I don't really care for AppleScript, and would much prefer a bash solution.

To reiterate, I have a .pdf open in Preview, and I want to close the specific window accessing and displaying the file rather than terminating the entire program. I think this is possible, since there is a way with the OS to kill the window without bash.

I would also like to know how the OS interfaces with the shell when it closes a subprocess (window) of an application.

I can find the open .pdf, process, socket, node, et c. with lsof, but I am hesitant to go further with such information since AFAIK, I can kill the entire process (overkill) or close the port/socket (weird kill) with that information.

Thanks for helping me with this problem. It's really bothering me that my google abilities are failing me.

edit: added in Super User link for osascript enabling to add context.

Comment: `man ps` then `man kill` no need to look on the internet.

Comment: Yes, but, what signal would I use with kill to close a subunit of an application without terminating the whole application? The only signals I could find listed on the manual are either too blood-thirsty or too ineffective. What I've googled so far has been unhelpful as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach that you're taking won't work -- windows within an application are not separate to the degree that you can remotely force one to close without affecting the application as a whole.

Only solution I can think of does involve AppleScript. I'm not sure what you mean by "the plist option does not exist for me".

```
tell application "System Events"
    click first button of (first window of process "Preview" whose name is "example.png")
end tell
```

This is a bit more convoluted than usual because Preview.app is sandboxed, and thus not scriptable via normal methods -- I had to use UI scripting instead. (The "first button" that I'm clicking is the close button on the window.)

Comment: Sorry, I meant [this](http://superuser.com/questions/526624/how-do-i-close-a-window-from-an-application-passing-the-file-name) by plist enabling. 

Your solution does indeed work, and your workaround is clever, but is there really no way to close a window in a sandboxed app without "clicking" the "first button"?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. As far as I can tell, the application is simply invisible to normal AppleScript.